# Error librerías apache http

Tags: android-studio

Buenas a todos, normalmente utilizo estas librerías para realizar peticiones http desde la aplicación android, y las he copiado y pegado de un proyecto anterior donde si funcionaban bien, y al copiarlas en este nuevo proyecto no me las reconoce. ¿están obsoletas?

Quiero realizar una comunicacion cliente-servidor en el que manejo (altas bajas y modificaciones) los objetos de un inventario, por tanto unas veces sera descargar el inventario, y otra modificarlo.

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
```

Muchas gracias a todos.

**Clase que realiza la peticion http:**

```
class AsignarHoraAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
        {
            return POST("http://adb.hol.es/conectar1.php");
        }
        // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            listado();
        }

        public String POST(String url)
        {
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            String result = "";
            try
            {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                //make POST request to the given URL
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                // pass parameters in this way

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("op",op));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ref",listaBC.get(pulsado).getReferencia()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hEnt",hora));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("equipo",equipo));
                Log.i("Asyn", "referencia:"+listaBC.get(pulsado).getReferencia()+"|| op:"+op+"||equipo:"+equipo+"||hR:"+hora);

                //add data
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                // 8. Execute POST request to the given URL
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

                // 9. receive response as inputStream
                inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();

                // 10. convert inputstream to string
                if(inputStream != null)
                {
                    result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

                    Log.i("Asyn", "result: " + result);

                }

                //Si pasa por aquí se va a tomar x el culo mirar!!
                else
                {
                    result = "Did not work!";
                }

            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //Log.d("InputStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Como en este caso es una operacion de actualizar el inventario recibe del servidor 1 o 2 y por esto no hago nada con la cadena que recibo. Sé que deberia haber un control de la excepcion.

Comment: Agrega que deseas realizar, sin duda la opción es cambiar a HttpUrlConnection. por lo tanto agrega tu código y te ayudo a cambiarlo.

Comment: Gracias @Jorgesys, estás en todas muy amable ayudarnos a los más topres. Te he puesto la clase que utilizo para realizar la peticion.

Comment: Aquí nadie es torpe, todos aprendemos de los demás, dame un par de minutos ya que estoy algo ocupado y agrego a mi respuesta la versión con HTTPUrlConnection de tu pregunta original, :)

Comment: @Jorgesys, he leído que es mas recomendado la librería Volley que HTTPUrlConnection ... qué opinas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uno de los cambios en Android 6.0 (API 23) es la eliminación de las clases [Apache (Eliminación del cliente HTTP de Apache](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client)), por lo tanto han sido marcadas como obsoletas, puedes seguir usando estas clases definiendo el soporte "legacy":

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

o bajar el nivel de tu `compileSdkVersion` , **sin embargo no son soluciones ya que en algún momento debes evitar usar estas clases**,

Para establecer una correcta solución es cambiar a **[HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)**

En el sitio tenemos varios ejemplos del uso de esta Clase:

https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=httpurlconnection

Answer (score 0):

Es un problema del Gradle, lo he solucionado cambiando la version, esas librerías al parecer a partir de la 23 no se reconocen,

**compileSdkVersion 21**

Lo encontre en el foro inglés: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio
Respuesta traducida del enalce:

*HttpClient ya no se admite en sdk 23. Debe usar URLConnection o degradar a sdk 22 (compilar 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0')
Si necesita sdk 23, agregue esto a su gradle:*

```
Android {
     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

*También puede intentar descargar e incluir el contenedor HttpClient directamente en su proyecto o usar OkHttp en su lugar*

He cambiado la version pero al apsar de la 25 a la 21 me sale este error **Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'**

Comment: puedes agregar referencia de lo que dices, estas suponiendo!

Comment: @JackNavaRow lo saque de aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153318/httpclient-wont-import-in-android-studio. Mi problema ahora es: Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'roundIcon' in package 'android'

Comment: Usar el soporte legacy o bajar el nivel de API no son una solución., in cluso si bajas el nivel, no podrás usar clases, propiedades o atributos como el que comentas. Que deseas realizar una petición? una descarga? agrega esto a tu pregunta.

Comment: @user2070274 traduce la respuesta y colocala!