# Error Commons-logging defines classes that conflict with classes now provided by Android

Tags: android-studio, google-play-services

Al poner en `release` una aplicación que usa mapas de google:

Uso Android studio 3.0.1

**app.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.webserveis.app.quickmapview"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.0.1"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.master.android:permissionhelper:1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.9'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Me salta ese error:

> Error:Error: commons-logging defines classes that conflict with
>   classes now provided by Android. Solutions include finding newer
>   versions or alternative libraries that don't have the same problem
>   (for example, for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead),
>   or repackaging the library using something like jarjar.
>   [DuplicatePlatformClasses]

Creo que es en la librería `com.opencsv:opencsv:3.9` que usa funciones obsoletas

Comment: Donde podrìa ver el código de com.opencsv?

Comment: Si es lo que intento encontrar también he visto que hay la 4.1 y estoy probando con exclude y si funciona la parte que utilizo solo leer .csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al parecer la dependencia de OpenCsv

implementation 'com.opencsv:opencsv:3.9'

usa [Libraries apache las cuales son obsoletas y se aconseja reemplazar por HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client), por esa razón te sugiere:

> for httpclient use HttpUrlConnection or okhttp instead

una opción es excluir estas libraries, lo cual puede provocar no funcione correctamente tu aplicación:

```
android {

   configurations {
        all {
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        }
    }
   ...
   ...
}
```

como otra opción, activar el modo legacy para soportar estas libraries apache:

```
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
```

Ejemplo:

[Error librerías apache http](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/113475/error-librer%C3%ADas-apache-http/113484#113484)

Comment: configurations se pone fuera de android { } en el app.graddle?

Comment: @Webserveis al nivel de android, edite la respuesta. Acabo de ver que esa library usa en su mayoria las clases de org.apache.commons, por lo que puede funcionar esa opcion!

Comment: He subido oencsv:4.1 y con eso me funciona
    implementation('com.opencsv:opencsv:4.1') {
        exclude module: 'httpclient'
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
Ya que solo httpclient daba igual error

Comment: Con eso tambien funciona, 
  configurations {
        all {
            exclude module: 'httpclient'
            exclude module: 'commons-logging'
        }
    }

Comment: @Webserveis de hecho baje la librerìa  3.9 al revisar el código  ùnicamente usa org.apache.commons nada relacionado a http!, actualice mi repuesta hehe