# No puedo compilar mi app en Android Studio 3.3.2

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo el Siguiente problema: Tengo una APP algo antigua, cuando la abrí en la nueva versión de android studio 3.3.2  y compilé la aplicacion, me sale el siguiente error.

Necesito por favor su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'pe.gob.senasa.asistenciacentral'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 5
        versionName '1.5'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'


}
```

---

Actualización:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'pe.gob.senasa.asistenciacentral'
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 5
        versionName '1.5'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

}

dependencies {
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.1'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
}
```

Ese es la nueva configuracion, pero ahora me sale este mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes actualizado el android studio?

Comment: Muchos errores se dan porque tienes desactualizado el android studio y sus plugins

Comment: Ami me paso lo mismo no hubo solución, así que con el android estudio actualizado me toco crear una nueva app vacía y pasar cada activity correspondiente en pocas palabras pasar todo el código java y xml a la nueva y fue un éxito.

Answer (score 0):

Lo ideal en este proyecto es actualizar ya que este estilo no existe en las support library 22,

> TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse not found

cambia el   `compileSdkVersion` y `targetSdkVersion`  a una versión mayor, asimismo las versiones definidas en tus dependencias:

```
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:???'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:???'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:???'


}
```

con esto debe poder encontrar el estilo y podrás compilar tu aplicación.

---

Incluso veo que en el proyecto se hace uso de Apache Lbiraries:

```
   useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
```

Estas library son obsoletas, debes usar la clase `HttpUrlConnection` del SDK

[App Android crashea al obtener un HttpResponse<JsonNode>](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277789/app-android-crashea-al-obtener-un-httpresponsejsonnode/277941#277941)

Comment: Hola cambien  lo que indicaste pero ahora me sales en estos errores.  ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0.
Show Details
Affected Modules: app

Comment: @LuisEnriqueUríasHernandez agrega en tu pregunta que cambios realizaste en tu build.gradle

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys♦ acabo de subir el build.gradle, muchas gracias de ante mano.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo no implementar `implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:###'` directamente, ya que al hacer eso te descargará librerías que no necesitas y tu aplicación pesará más. Es mejor solo implementar las que necesites tal como lo recomienda Android https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Y referente a tu problema verifica que tengas descargado el SDK para compilar Api 28.
Tools --> SDK Manager --> Android SDK

Otra también puedes limpiar y reconstruir el proyecto, eso luego lo soluciona.
 1. Build --> Clean Project. 
 2. Build --> Rebuild Project